# 2 or more shapes in a single drawable?

Tags: android, xml

Is it possible to to have 2 or more shapes in a single drawable?
I'm trying to create something like this:

[image]

I have one drawable token.xml which creates one of the rectangles with black color and a white border:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<!-- view background color -->
<solid
    android:color="@android:color/black" >
</solid>

<!-- view border color and width -->
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@android:color/white" >
</stroke>
```

any idea?

Comment: You can add as many shapes you want in a [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html). In your case (1), you want a gradient square and a white cross over it. In your case (2), you want the same, but with another smaller white square added.

Comment: do not use any dirty tricks in xml files, instead just create a custom `Shape` class and draw your shapes in `draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint)`, then pass your custom `Shape` object to a `ShapeDrawable` ctor

Comment: 1/4 of the whole drawable... in total. because it's indeed 1/2 wide and 1/2 tall. Hmmm... it possibly has to be a 9 patch (`<nine-patch ... />`). 2x2 pixel (3 transparent and 1 white) plus the 1px border with the black markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="9dp"
            android:height="9dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#f000"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:top="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="5dp" android:right="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="3dp"
            android:height="3dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#f00"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="1dp" android:left="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" android:right="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="3dp"
            android:height="3dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#0f0"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:top="5dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:right="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="3dp"
            android:height="3dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#0f0"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:right="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="3dp"
            android:height="3dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#f00"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: what if his grid is not 2x2 but 10x10? would you add a hundred <item>s?

Comment: the title says: `2 or more shapes in a single drawable?` so 100 is for sure > 2

Comment: i give it for reference if it is not usable then ignore it

Comment: i am just trying to tell you that this solution with `layer-list` is a bad idea

Comment: if you have any batter then why you didn't post?

Comment: it is not about if i answer or not, it is about letting you know that xml drawables are not best solution for everything, but if you really want to know then see [here](http://pastebin.com/qsRzSfpQ)